# yii2 | как реализовать push notification уведомления на телефон

Tags: yii2, уведомления

Я для своего мобильного проекта использую yii2 и на нем написано API,
Задался вопросом, как можно на yii2 реализовать  notification уведомления на телефон, есть ли уже готовые инструменты, или нужно писать с нуля и подключать какие то другие сервисы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через Firebase. Вот пример

```
    public function sendNotification($fcm_token,$title,$body,$type,$priority,$object,$user_id)
{
    if (is_object($object)){
        $object = $object->toArray();
    }
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key='.'Ваш Firebase ключ'
    );

    $fields = [];


    if (is_array($fcm_token)){
        $fields['registration_ids'] = $fcm_token;
    }
    else{
        $fields['to'] = $fcm_token;
    }

    $fields['content_aviable'] = true;
    $fields['priority'] = $priority;
    $fields['notification'] = ['title' => $title,'body' => $body,'sound' => 'default','type' => $type];
    $fields['data'] = ['title' => $title,'body' => $body,'sound' => 'default','type' => $type,'object' => $object];
    $fields['notification']['context_data'] = $object;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Для отправки смс мы на работе используем сторонний сервис. ПРосто отправляем туда запрос с данными что и кому отправить. Для реализации уведомлений рекомендую сразу обратить внимание на паттерн декоратор. Будет проще потом расширить каналы уведомлений.

Comment: у меня не смс уведомления будут, а я хочу сделать уведомления в приложение. По вашему ответу я понял, что нужно использовать сторонний сервис. Спасибо!

Comment: Я полагаю, автор вопроса хочет `push notifications`, а не sms.